# MySQL/InnoDB transactions with table locks in InnoDB

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, locking, innodb

I did a lot of research and I found a lot of information about all the relevant topics. However, I am not confident that I do now understand, how to put all this information together properly.

This application is written in PHP.

For queries I use PDO.

The MySQL database is configured as InnoDB.

### What I need

```
SELECT ... FROM tableA;

// PHP looks at what comes back and does some logic.
INSERT INTO tableA ...;
INSERT INTO tableB ...;
```

Conditions:

- The INSERTs need to be atomic. If one of them fails I want to roll back.
- No reads and writes from/to tableA are allowed to happen between the SELECT and the INSERT from/into tableA.

This to me looks like a very simple problem. Yet I am not able to figure out, how to do this properly. So my question is:

### What is the best approach?

This is an outline for my current plan, heavily simplified:

```
try {
  SET autocommit = 0;

  BLOCK TABLES tableA WRITE, tableB WRITE;

  SELECT ... FROM tableA;

  INSERT INTO tableA ...;
  INSERT INTO tableB ...;

  COMMIT;

  UNLOCK TABLES;

  SET autocommit = 1;
}

catch {
  ROLLBACK;

  UNLOCK TABLES;

  SET autocommit = 1;
}
```

I feel like there is a lot that could be done better, but I don't know how :/

### Why do it like this?

- I need some kind of transaction to be able to do a rollback if INSERTs fail.
- I need to lock tableA to make sure that no other INSERTs or UPDATEs take place.
- Transactions and table locks don't work well together
  (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables-and-transactions.html)
- I want to use autocommit as a standard throughout the rest of my application, which is why I set it back to "1" at the end.
- I am really not sure about this: But I somewhere picked up, that after locking a table, I can (from within the current connection) only query to this table until I unlock it (this does not make sense to me). This is why I locked tableB too, altough otherwise I wouldn't need to.

### I am open for completely different approaches

I am open for any suggestion within the framework conditions PHP, MySQL, PDO and InnoDB.

**Thank You!**

---

**Edit 1 (2018-06-01)**

I feel like my problem/question needs some more clarification.

### Starting point:

If have two tables, *t1* and *t2*.

*t1* has multiple columns of non-unique values.

The specifics of *t2* are irrelevant for this problem.

### What I want to do:

Step by step:

1. Select multiple columns and rows from *t1*.
2. In PHP analyse the retrieved data. Based on the results of this analysis put together a dataset.
3. INSERT parts of the dataset into *t1* and parts of it into *t2*.

Additional information:

- The INSERTs into the 2 tables must be atomic. This can be achieved using transactions.
- No INSERTs from a different connection are allowed to occur between steps 1 and 3. This is very important, because every single INSERT into *t1* has to occur with full awareness of the current state of the table. I'll best describe this in more detail. I will leave *t2* out of this for now, to make things easier to understand.

  Imagine this sequence of events (connections con1 and con2):

  1. con1: SELECT ... FROM t1 WHERE xyz;
  2. con1: PHP processes the information.
  3. con2: SELECT ... FROM t1 WHERE uvw;
  4. con2: PHP processes the information.
  5. con1: INSERT INTO t1 ...;
  6. con2: INSERT INTO t1 ...;

  So both connections see *t1* in the same state. However, they select different information. *Con1* takes the information gathered, does some logic with it and then INSERTs data into a new row in *t1*. *Con2* does the same, but using different information.

  The problem is this: Both connections INSERTed data based on calculations that did not take into account whatever the other connection inserted into *t1*, because this information wasn't there when they read from *t1*.

  *Con2* might have inserted a row into *t1* that would have met the WHERE-conditions of *con1*'s SELECT-statement. In other words: Had *con2* inserted its row earlier, *con1* might have created completely different data to insert into *t1*. This is to say: The two INSERTs might have completely invalidated each others inserts.

  This is why I want to make sure, that only one connection can work with the data in *t1* at a time. No other connection is allowed to write, but also no other connection is allowed to read until the current connection is done.

  I hope this clarifies things a bit... :/

### Thoughts:

My thoughts were:

1. I need to make the INSERTs into the 2 tables atomic. --> I will use a transaction for this. Something like this:

   ```
   try {
     $pdo->beginTransaction();
     // INSERT INTO t1 ...
     // INSERT INTO t2 ...
     $pdo->commit();
   }
   catch (Exception $e) {
     $pdo->rollBack();
     throw $e;
   }
   ```
2. I need to make sure, no other connection writes to or reads from *t1*. This is where I decided that I need LOCK TABLES.
3. Assuming I had to use LOCK TABLES, I was confronted with the problem that LOCK TABLES is not transaction aware. Which is why I decided to go with the solution proposed here (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables-and-transactions.html) and also in multiple answers on stackoverflow.

But I wasn't happy with how the code looked like, which is why I came here to ask this (meanwhile rather lengthy) question.

---

**Edit 2 (2018-06-01)**

This process will not run often. So there is no significant need for high performance and effiency. This, of course, also means that the chances of two of those processes infering with eachother are rather minute. Stil, I'd like to make sure nothing can happen.

Comment: Dont you mean B and C? SELECT from A.. INSERT INTO A is kinda pointless.

Comment: No, I really mean SELECT from A.. INSERT INTO A. These are the steps:
(1.) SELECT from A.
(2.) PHP looks at the result, does some logic, puts together data to insert.
(3.) INSERT INTO A.
Why is this pointless? What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe my original question was unclear. I rewrote this part of my question to be less ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Case 1:**

```
BEGIN;
INSERT ..
INSERT ..
COMMIT;
```

Other connections will not see the inserted rows until after the commit.  That is, `BEGIN...COMMIT` made the two inserts "atomic".

If anything fails, you still need the try/catch to deal with it.

Do not use `LOCK TABLES` on InnoDB tables.

Don't bother with `autocommit`; `BEGIN..COMMIT` overrides it.

My statements apply to (probably) all frameworks.  (Except that some do not have "try" and "catch".)

**Case 2**:  Lock a row in anticipation of possibly modifying it:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT ... FROM t1 FOR UPDATE;
... work with the values SELECTed
UPDATE t1 ...;
COMMIT;
```

This keeps others away from the rows `SELECTed` until after the `COMMIT`.

**Case 3**:  Sometimes IODKU is useful to do two things in a single atomic statement:

```
INSERT ...
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...
```

instead of

```
BEGIN;
SELECT ... FOR UPDATE;
if no row found
    INSERT ...;
else
    UPDATE ...;
COMMIT;
```

**Class 4**:  Classic banking example:

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE accounts SET balance = balance - 1000.00 WHERE id='me';
... What if crash occurs here? ...
UPDATE accounts SET balance = balance + 1000.00 WHERE id='you';
COMMIT;
```

If the system crashes between the two `UPDATEs`, the first update will be undone.  This keeps the system from losing track of the funds transfer.

**Case 5:** Perhaps close to what the OP wants.  It is mostly a combination of Cases 2 and 1.

```
BEGIN;
SELECT ... FROM t1 FOR UPDATE;   -- see note below
... work with the values SELECTed
INSERT INTO t1 ...;
COMMIT;
```

Notes on Case 5:  The `SELECT..FOR UPDATE` must include any rows that you don't want the other connection to see.  This has the effect of delaying the other connection until this connection `COMMITs`.  (Yes, this feels a lot like `LOCK TABLES t1 WRITE`.)

**Case 6:**  The "processing" that needs to be inside the BEGIN..COMMIT will take too long.  (Example: the typical online shopping cart.)

This needs a locking mechanism outside of InnoDB's transactions.  One way (useful for shopping cart) is to use a row in some extra table, and have everyone check it.  Another way (more practical within a single connection) is to use `GET_LOCK('foo')` and it's friends.

**General Discussion**

All of the above examples lock only the row(s) involved, not the entire table(s).  This makes the action much less invasive, and allows for the system to handle much more activity.

Also, read about MVCC.  This is a general technique used under the cover to let one connection see the values of the table(s) at some instant in time, *even while other connections are modifying the table(s)*.

"Prevent inserts" -- With MVCC, if you start a `SELECT`, it is like getting a snapshot in time of everything you are looking at.  You won't see the `INSERTs` until after you complete the transaction that the `SELECT` is in.  You can have your cake and eat it, too.  That is, it appears as if the inserts were blocked, but you get the performance benefit of them happening in parallel.  Magic.

Comment: Thank you! However, I am afraid, I do not see how this solves my problem :/ How does this ensure that no inserts take place between SELECT from tableA and INSERT to it? I know how to work with transactions - that is not my problem. My problem is, how to achieve BOTH: (1) atomic inserts (-->transaction) and (2) preventing inserts into tableA from different connections (-->table lock [?]). And since table locks aren't transaction aware, I went for autocommit (which is suggested in the MySQL documentation - see link in my question).

Comment: Also, could you please expand on why using LOCK TABLES on InnoDB tables should be avoided? And: Is there a way to prevent inserts to a table without using LOCK TABLES?

Comment: @wire417 - I added more cases, plus gave a brief overview of MVCC, which might be the clue you are missing.

Comment: I really, really appreciate the time and effort you put into your answer! However, I still feel like my problem isn't solved. I feel like this is one of two things: me miscommunicating the problem or me not seeing something really obvious. I updated my original question to deliver a lot more detail on the problem and my thoughts. I will also comment here on why I believe that the cases you provided do not solve my problem. Thank you for all the time you put into this!!!

Comment: Case 2: There are 2 problems with this, that I can see. (1) I can not use FOR UPDATE to lock a row that does not exists yet. Which means: I can't use it to prevent INSERTs from a different connection. (2) Even if I could use it to prevent inserts, this other connection (con2) could still read information from other rows in the table (which weren't locked by con1) and later (after all relevant locks were released) insert data based on this information. However, con1 might have just inserted data that would have changed the outcome of con2's calculations, had it had the data.

Comment: Case 3: There again are 2 problems, as far as I can tell. (1) This is not a matter of uniqueness (which you didn't know, of course, because I hadn't included this info in my original question). (2) Even if it were a matter of uniqueness: On discovering that there is a duplicate, (under the cirumstances of this question) I would still need to go back right to the start, read from the table again, process the gathered information and the try another insert, in the hope that this time no other connection interfered.

Comment: @wire417 - If two concurrent transactions insert/update/delete the same row (according to a `UNIQUE` key) (new or existing row), I think there will be a deadlock, causing one of the transactions to be rolled back.  That is, the conflict is so severe that InnoDB punts on trying to resolve it.

Comment: Case 1 and 4: As far as I can tell, these are just transactions making sure that my INSERTs or UPDATEs are atomic. Finally, MVCC: Thank you for pointing me in this direction, but I already am aware of this behaviour (though I'll further dig into it). However, I feel like this behaviour is less part of the solution and more part of the problem in this case... "the performance benefit of them happening in parallel" is exactly what I do not want to happen. P.S.: I will edit this info into my original question: This process will not be run often.

Comment: @wire417 - The usual recovery from any kind of error in a transaction is to `ROLLBACK` what has been done so far, then start back at the `BEGIN`.  This provides a fresh look at the data.

Comment: @wire417 - Transactional integrity is probably aimed at dealing with a small number of rows.  Reading most or all of a table as part of transaction is "abnormal".  There are some situations where pulling the bulky `SELECT` and processing out of the transaction is actually the practical and efficient answer.  (I would prefer to see more concrete code.)

Comment: @wire417 - While reading about MVCC, take note of "transaction isolation mode" (Dirty, Uncommitted, Committed, Seralizable).  It's enough to make one's head spin, but there may be a 'mode' that works better for you.  I think Serializable is close to `LOCK TABLES`.

Comment: "Case 5" solves my problem. You are right: these aren't all too many rows. I might, however, need to lock all the rows of the table using FOR UPDATE, since con1 does not know which rows will match the SELECT-query of con2. But maybe I will find some workaround for this. Also I will take a closer look at the transaction isolation modes. Again: Thank you very, very much for your time and patience :)

Comment: @wire417 - I made some more updates.  Maybe you need Case 6.  Maybe you need `LOCK TABLES`.